# Installed Packages Failing to Show up on Alpine Linux in Docker Container

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, fontconfig

I'm trying to deploy a Next.js app in a Docker container where I'd like to use the `sharp` npm library to work on SVG with text.

Because `sharp` relies on the host system's `fontconfig` library for its handling of fonts (which is no issue on my local system when doing local development), I need to install it on the Alpine Linux system on top of which I'm running the app in the Docker container.

When I'm installing the packages using `docker build -t test .` on the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:21-alpine AS base
FROM base AS deps

RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat freetype pango vips fontconfig font-dejavu ttf-freefont

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi

FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN npm run build
RUN npm rebuild --verbose sharp

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

I'm getting the following build messages:

```
Step 5/33 : RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat freetype pango vips fontconfig font-dejavu ttf-freefont
 ---> Running in fdb2fb972a3b
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/81) Installing libexpat (2.5.0-r2)
(2/81) Installing brotli-libs (1.1.0-r1)
(3/81) Installing libbz2 (1.0.8-r6)
(4/81) Installing libpng (1.6.40-r0)
(5/81) Installing freetype (2.13.2-r0)
(6/81) Installing fontconfig (2.14.2-r4)
(7/81) Installing encodings (1.0.7-r1)
(8/81) Installing libfontenc (1.1.7-r4)
(9/81) Installing mkfontscale (1.2.2-r4)
(10/81) Installing font-dejavu (2.37-r5)

...

(79/81) Installing libwebpdemux (1.3.2-r0)
(80/81) Installing libwebpmux (1.3.2-r0)
(81/81) Installing vips (8.15.0-r0)
Executing busybox-1.36.1-r15.trigger
Executing fontconfig-2.14.2-r4.trigger
Executing mkfontscale-1.2.2-r4.trigger
Executing glib-2.78.3-r0.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20230506-r0.trigger
Executing shared-mime-info-2.4-r0.trigger
Executing gdk-pixbuf-2.42.10-r6.trigger
OK: 128 MiB in 98 packages
```

But afterwards when I run the shell in the live container `docker run -it test /bin/sh`, according the command of listing installed packages `apk list -i`, those packages are nowhere to be found:

```
WARNING: opening from cache https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main: No such file or directory
WARNING: opening from cache https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/community: No such file or directory
alpine-baselayout-3.4.3-r2 x86_64 {alpine-baselayout} (GPL-2.0-only) [installed]
alpine-baselayout-data-3.4.3-r2 x86_64 {alpine-baselayout} (GPL-2.0-only) [installed]
alpine-keys-2.4-r1 x86_64 {alpine-keys} (MIT) [installed]
apk-tools-2.14.0-r5 x86_64 {apk-tools} (GPL-2.0-only) [installed]
busybox-1.36.1-r15 x86_64 {busybox} (GPL-2.0-only) [installed]
busybox-binsh-1.36.1-r15 x86_64 {busybox} (GPL-2.0-only) [installed]
ca-certificates-bundle-20230506-r0 x86_64 {ca-certificates} (MPL-2.0 AND MIT) [installed]
libc-utils-0.7.2-r5 x86_64 {libc-dev} (BSD-2-Clause AND BSD-3-Clause) [installed]
libcrypto3-3.1.4-r2 x86_64 {openssl} (Apache-2.0) [installed]
libgcc-13.2.1_git20231014-r0 x86_64 {gcc} (GPL-2.0-or-later AND LGPL-2.1-or-later) [installed]
libssl3-3.1.4-r2 x86_64 {openssl} (Apache-2.0) [installed]
libstdc++-13.2.1_git20231014-r0 x86_64 {gcc} (GPL-2.0-or-later AND LGPL-2.1-or-later) [installed]
musl-1.2.4_git20230717-r4 x86_64 {musl} (MIT) [installed]
musl-utils-1.2.4_git20230717-r4 x86_64 {musl} (MIT AND BSD-2-Clause AND GPL-2.0-or-later) [installed]
scanelf-1.3.7-r2 x86_64 {pax-utils} (GPL-2.0-only) [installed]
ssl_client-1.36.1-r15 x86_64 {busybox} (GPL-2.0-only) [installed]
zlib-1.3-r2 x86_64 {zlib} (Zlib) [installed]
```

I've put in bold the **WARNING**s that look somewhat suspicious to me. But honestly, I have no clue how to make sure how to install and make `fontconfig` work here. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the last `FROM X AS Y` statement you have? These are called docker stages and are independent each other.

Comment: You've excluded a bunch of information here that would be necessary to answer this question. Please include a [mcve] -- a minimal, *complete* Dockerfile that reproduces the behavior you're asking about (and the specific command lines your using to build and run the image).

Comment: @slackmart `FROM base AS runner` is the last such statement

Comment: You're installing the packages in the `deps` stage but not referencing that stage anywhere else. Either change `FROM base AS runner` to `FROM deps AS runner` or move the `RUN apk add...` line down into the `runner` stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're installing the packages into your `deps` stage, but all the following stages are `FROM base ...`:

```
$ grep FROM Dockerfile
FROM node:21-alpine AS base
FROM base AS deps
FROM base AS builder
FROM base AS runner
```

You would need to change `FROM base` to `FROM deps` in the final stage (`FROM deps AS runner`) in order to see those packages.

Comment: Gosh, that was it. Thanks a lot!